# Triangular matrix generated by prime numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $M= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots 0  \\
2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots 0 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & \cdots 0 \\
5 & 3 & 2 & \cdots 0 \\
7 & 5 & 3 & \cdots 0 \\
\ldots & \ldots & & \\
p_n & p_{n-1} & p_{n-2} & \cdots 1
\end{pmatrix}$

I want to know if all of its square sub-minors $M'[r_1, r_2, \cdots r_t| c_1, c_2, \cdots c_t]$ satisfying $r_k\geq c_k$, for all $1 \leq k \leq t$,  have non-zero determinant.

I can see that this is true for $t=1, 2$.

I would also be happy if someone directs me to calculate this condition till $n=100$, say.

Comment: The determinant of a triangular matrix is equal to the product of its diagonal elements. In the present case, it is always $1.$

Comment: Hi @user376343, I understand that the big matrix $M$ is non-singular (or det $\neq 0$). My question is about non-singularity of all its proper minors of the form defined above.

Comment: If the given matrix is triangular, all its principal minors are triangular. The determinant of each of them is $1.$

Comment: @user376343, sure. These are the minors where $r_k = c_k$ and I agree with you that these will be upper triangular with $1$'s on the diagonal. This is one case and not too hard to see. I can't justify non-singularity for minors where $r_k<c_k$. For instance, can we say the $3 \times 3$ minor of the form $\begin{pmatrix} p_{n-2} & p_{n-3} & p_{n-4}\\ p_{n-1} & p_{n-2} & p_{n-3} \\ p_n & p_{n-1} & p_{n-2} \end{pmatrix}$ has det $\neq 0$?

Comment: $M'[r_1, r_2, \cdots r_t| c_1, c_2, \cdots c_t]$ in your question makes me think that you are only interested in principal minors "along the main diagonal".

Comment: @user376343, I'm not aware if this is the standard notation, if you know of a notation, I'm open to editing my  question easier to follow. Until then, I clarify that I'm interested in checking non-singularity for all minors as described in the question; not just the principal ones.

Comment: The determinant for 3x3-submatrices (without zeros) can be expressed by this polynomial $D=p_3^3 -2 p_2 p_3 p_4 - p_1 p_3 p_5 + p_1 p_4^2 + p_2^2 p_5$ where the $p_k$ are filled with consecutive primes. For the consecutive primes $p=23..41$ the determinant ***is zero***.

Answer (score 1):

***Counterexample:***
The determinant for $3 \times 3$-submatrices (without zeros) can be expressed by this polynomial 
$$D=p_3^3−2p_2p_3p_4−p_1p_3p_5+p_1p_4^2+p_2^2p_5$$
 where the $p_k$ are filled with consecutive primes. For the consecutive primes $p_1=23 \ldots p_5=41$ the determinant is zero ($D=0$).

Pari/GP: `matdet([31,29,23;37,31,29;41,37,31])`

Comment: thanks a lot! This is a simple and very clean counter example. Can you share some insight into how you found this? I'm asking because running an exhaustive search seemed hard. In any case, thanks again.

Comment: @user599553 - just brute force. Using the $D=$ formula, filling in for $p_1$ to $p_5$ sets of 5 consecutive primes with $p_1$ chosen by $p_1=3$,$p_1=5$, ... This is a very simple operation in Pari/GP and was done in less than a second...

Comment: @user599553 - additional remark: Well, I've tried a bit with prime-difference-patterns, which means in the above formula for $D=$ instead of $p_1,p_2,...,p_5$ I inserted $p_1,p_1+d_2,p_1+d_2+d_3$ and so on. The resulting new expression for $D$ gave some curious pattern, especially when I set the prime-differences $d_2=d_4$ or similar conditions, but I lost mood and didn't check this exhaustingly.